# Keep Conditional formatting after clear in script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
shUserForm.getRange("C7").clear();
```

After I run the script, the cell is cleared, but also the conditional formatting of that cell.
Is it possible to keep the conditional formatting?

Comment: If you want to clear only cell value, how about using `clearContent()` like `shUserForm.getRange("C7").clearContent();` instead of `clear()`? [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your issue was resolved, how about posting it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.clear()` on a range clears the range of contents *and* formats.

Instead use `.clearContent()` to clear the content of the range, leaving the formatting intact.

[See Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) for available methods on ranges. Also thanks to @[Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)'s comment on OP.